# Key-value map in pl/sql using number as index

Tags: dictionary, indexing, plsql, types, key-value

I want to store number values in a map, and the indexes should be also number type. How can I implement this?

So instead of this:

`TYPE number_list IS TABLE of NUMBER(38) INDEX BY varchar(22);`

I want to write this:
`TYPE number_list IS TABLE of NUMBER(38) INDEX BY NUMBER(38);`

But the plsql says, that is unsupported table index type. How can I solve this? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to create an `associative array` (an Oracle Collection). For a numeric index you need index specif either `binary_integer` or `pls_integer`

> For associative arrays (also known as index-by tables), use the
> syntax:
>
> TYPE type_name IS TABLE OF element_type [NOT NULL]    INDEX BY
> [BINARY_INTEGER | PLS_INTEGER | VARCHAR2(size_limit)];    INDEX BY
> key_type;
>
> The key_type can be numeric, either BINARY_INTEGER or PLS_INTEGER.